# How to add a property on a model class that's not related to the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

so i have this model class:

```
[Table("items")]
public class items
{
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
   //   public int test { get; set; } crashes
}
```

I use entity framework. my table has `id,text,value` and `test` property is not part of it. I populate my `DbSet` like this

`public DbSet<items> items { get; set; }`

Odd enough, it doesn't crash if i add something like `public List<string> test { get; set; }`.

What should i do? i originally wanted to add a `bool?` property.

edit:
I was thinking of making a new class that will inherit the model, but i will have to remap/re-populate it.

Comment: `items` is a data model associated with you database. If you want additional unrelated properties for use in a view, you should be using a view model.

Comment: Use the *[Ignore]* data annotation

Answer (score 5):

You can add the `NotMapped` attribute.

For example:

```
[Table("items")]
public class items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh i see. let me try. are there any downsides with this solution?